# What is a formal definition of strong one-time-secure signatures?

Tags: hash-signature

What is a formal definition of strong one-time-secure signatures?

I know the Lamport's scheme is one of them, but what is the global definition of it?

Comment: @dingrite: Actually, I would disagree that Lamport is always the "best"; a Winternitz signature is often better (significantly shorter, at the cost of some computation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the usual security game for digital signatures, but the adversary is only allowed to make a single signature query.

In other words:

1. The simulator generates a key pair, and gives the adversary the verification key.
2. The adversary sends the simulator a message $m$. The simulator signs the message and sends the signature $\sigma$ to the adversary.
3. The adversary outputs his forgery $(m',\sigma')$.

The adversary wins if $\sigma'$ is a valid signature on $m'$ and $(m',\sigma') \not= (m,\sigma)$.

In the usual signature game, the second step can be repeated many times.